# how to send sensor data 's real time and data to firebase using arduino?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, sensors

I am only able to send the timestamp but not the actual time to firebase using the arduino code below

```
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& PIR1Object = jsonBuffer.createObject();
  JsonObject& PIR1ONTime = PIR1Object.createNestedObject("timestamp");
  PIR1Object["PIR_1_ON"] = 1;
  PIR1ONTime[".sv"] = "timestamp";
  Firebase.push("/sensor/PIR_1", PIR1Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by not actual time?Can you share screen shot of results ?
The method you have chosen it will save the time in UNIX format.For testing purposes you can convert the unix form to human read form using this [site](https://www.epochconverter.com/). On app you might have to convert it depending on your language or need.